# Packaged Vagrant plugin not installed

Tags: plugins, vagrant

I have written a custom vagrant plugin (https://github.com/cthrax/guest-tinycore) that when packaged as a gem and installed with 'vagrant plugin install /path/to/gem', states that it is installed successfully. However, when attempting to run any other vagrant command against the box, the plugin functionality is not available and I get the message:

> The plugin "guest-tinycore" could not be found. Please make sure that it is
>   properly installed via `vagrant plugin`. Note that plugins made for
>   Vagrant 1.0.x are not compatible with 1.1+ and this error will likely
>   continue to show when you use `plugin install` with a 1.0.x plugin.

However, if I take this plugin and move it into the Vagrant application itself, as a core plugin, Vagrant picks it up successfully and all functionality works.

I'm looking for some guidance as to why the packaged version is not picked up by Vagrant correctly. Below is the debug log from running 'vagrant up'. (I've removed the output from the "guest-capabilities" call, so that I can get under the character limit.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
     INFO global: Vagrant version: 1.3.5
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/box/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: box command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/destroy/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: destroy command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/halt/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: halt command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/help/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: help command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/init/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: init command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/package/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: package command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: plugin command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/provision/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: provision command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/reload/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: reload command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/resume/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: resume command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/ssh/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ssh command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/ssh_config/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ssh-config command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/status/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: status command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/suspend/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: suspend command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/up/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: up command
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/communicators/ssh/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ssh communicator
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/arch/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Arch guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/coreos/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: CoreOS guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/darwin/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Darwin guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/debian/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Debian guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/esxi/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ESXi guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/fedora/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Fedora guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/freebsd/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: FreeBSD guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/gentoo/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Gentoo guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/linux/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Linux guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/omnios/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: OmniOS guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/openbsd/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: OpenBSD guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/pld/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: PLD Linux guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/redhat/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: RedHat guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/solaris/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Solaris guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/solaris11/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Solaris 11 guest.
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/suse/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: SUSE guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/guests/ubuntu/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Ubuntu guest
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/hosts/arch/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Arch host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/hosts/bsd/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: BSD host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/hosts/freebsd/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: FreeBSD host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/hosts/gentoo/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Gentoo host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/hosts/linux/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Linux host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/hosts/opensuse/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: OpenSUSE host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/hosts/redhat/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Red Hat host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/hosts/slackware/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Slackware host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/hosts/windows/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Windows host
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/kernel_v1/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: kernel
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/kernel_v2/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: kernel
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: VirtualBox provider
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/provisioners/ansible/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ansible
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/provisioners/cfengine/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: CFEngine Provisioner
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/provisioners/chef/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: chef
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/provisioners/file/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: file
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/provisioners/puppet/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: puppet
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/provisioners/salt/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: salt
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/provisioners/shell/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: shell
 INFO vagrant: `vagrant` invoked: ["up"]
DEBUG vagrant: Creating Vagrant environment
 INFO environment: Environment initialized (#<Vagrant::Environment:0x00000100a0f928>)
 INFO environment:   - cwd: /Users/mbostwick/workspace/poseidon/app/vm
 INFO environment: Home path: /Users/mbostwick/.vagrant.d
 INFO environment: Local data path: /Users/mbostwick/workspace/poseidon/app/vm/.vagrant
DEBUG environment: Creating: /Users/mbostwick/workspace/poseidon/app/vm/.vagrant
DEBUG environment: Loading plugins from: /Users/mbostwick/.vagrant.d/plugins.json
 INFO environment: Loading plugin from JSON: guest-tinycore
ERROR root: Failed to load plugin: guest-tinycore
ERROR root:  -- Error: #<LoadError: cannot load such file -- guest-tinycore>
ERROR root:  -- Backtrace:
ERROR root: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant.rb:193:in `require_plugin'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:744:in `block in load_plugins'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:741:in `each'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:741:in `load_plugins'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:132:in `initialize'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/bin/vagrant:74:in `new'
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/bin/vagrant:74:in `<top (required)>'
/Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `load'
/Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `<main>'
 INFO interface: error: The plugin "guest-tinycore" could not be found. Please make sure that it is
properly installed via `vagrant plugin`. Note that plugins made for
Vagrant 1.0.x are not compatible with 1.1+ and this error will likely
continue to show when you use `plugin install` with a 1.0.x plugin.

[31mThe plugin "guest-tinycore" could not be found. Please make sure that it is
properly installed via `vagrant plugin`. Note that plugins made for
Vagrant 1.0.x are not compatible with 1.1+ and this error will likely
continue to show when you use `plugin install` with a 1.0.x plugin.
[0m
 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_load
 INFO environment: Initializing config...
 INFO loader: Set :default = "/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/config/default.rb"
DEBUG loader: Populating proc cache for "/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/config/default.rb"
DEBUG loader: Load procs for pathname: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/config/default.rb
 INFO loader: Set :root = #<Pathname:/Users/mbostwick/workspace/poseidon/app/vm/Vagrantfile>
DEBUG loader: Populating proc cache for #<Pathname:/Users/mbostwick/workspace/poseidon/app/vm/Vagrantfile>
DEBUG loader: Load procs for pathname: /Users/mbostwick/workspace/poseidon/app/vm/Vagrantfile
 INFO loader: Loading configuration in order: [:default, :home, :root]
DEBUG loader: Loading from: default (evaluating)
DEBUG loader: Loading from: root (evaluating)
DEBUG provisioner: Provisioner defined: shell
DEBUG loader: Configuration loaded successfully, finalizing and returning
DEBUG hosts: Host path search classes: [VagrantPlugins::HostWindows::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostSlackware::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostRedHat::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostOpenSUSE::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostFreeBSD::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostGentoo::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostArch::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostBSD::Host, VagrantPlugins::HostLinux::Host]
 INFO hosts: Host class: VagrantPlugins::HostBSD::Host
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x00000100a69a68>
 INFO cli: CLI: [] "up" []
DEBUG cli: Invoking command class: VagrantPlugins::CommandUp::Command []
DEBUG command: 'Up' each target VM...
DEBUG command: Getting target VMs for command. Arguments:
DEBUG command:  -- names: []
DEBUG command:  -- options: {:provider=>nil}
DEBUG command: Loading all machines...
 INFO command: Active machine found with name default. Using provider: virtualbox
 INFO environment: Getting machine: default (virtualbox)
 INFO environment: Uncached load of machine.
 INFO loader: Set :vm_default = []
 INFO loader: Loading configuration in order: [:default, :home, :root, :vm_default]
DEBUG loader: Loading from: default (cache)
DEBUG loader: Loading from: root (cache)
DEBUG loader: Configuration loaded successfully, finalizing and returning
 INFO box_collection: Searching for box: poseidon (virtualbox) in /Users/mbostwick/.vagrant.d/boxes/poseidon/virtualbox/metadata.json
 INFO box_collection: Box found: poseidon (virtualbox)
 INFO environment: Box exists with Vagrantfile. Reloading machine config.
 INFO loader: Set :box_poseidon_virtualbox = #<Pathname:/Users/mbostwick/.vagrant.d/boxes/poseidon/virtualbox/Vagrantfile>
DEBUG loader: Populating proc cache for #<Pathname:/Users/mbostwick/.vagrant.d/boxes/poseidon/virtualbox/Vagrantfile>
DEBUG loader: Load procs for pathname: /Users/mbostwick/.vagrant.d/boxes/poseidon/virtualbox/Vagrantfile
 INFO loader: Loading configuration in order: [:default, :box_poseidon_virtualbox, :home, :root, :vm_default]
DEBUG loader: Loading from: default (cache)
DEBUG loader: Loading from: box_poseidon_virtualbox (evaluating)
DEBUG loader: Upgrading config from version 1 to 2
DEBUG loader: Upgrading config to version 2
DEBUG loader: Upgraded to version 2 with 0 warnings and 0 errors
DEBUG loader: Loading from: root (cache)
DEBUG loader: Configuration loaded successfully, finalizing and returning
 INFO machine: Initializing machine: default
 INFO machine:   - Provider: VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Provider
 INFO machine:   - Box: #<Vagrant::Box:0x00000100d4d7e8>
 INFO machine:   - Data dir: /Users/mbostwick/workspace/poseidon/app/vm/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox
DEBUG virtualbox: Instantiating the driver for machine ID: "0dd96364-f3ae-4bbd-a116-279894338e3f"
 INFO base: VBoxManage path: VBoxManage
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "--version"]
DEBUG subprocess: Command not in installer, not touching env vars.
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: 4.2.18r88780
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
DEBUG meta: Finding driver for VirtualBox version: 4.2.18
 INFO meta: Using VirtualBox driver: VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Driver::Version_4_2
 INFO base: VBoxManage path: VBoxManage
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "showvminfo", "0dd96364-f3ae-4bbd-a116-279894338e3f"]
DEBUG subprocess: Command not in installer, not touching env vars.
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: Name:            vm_default_1382672231
Groups:          /
Guest OS:        Linux 2.6
UUID:            0dd96364-f3ae-4bbd-a116-279894338e3f

 INFO command: With machine: default (VirtualBox (0dd96364-f3ae-4bbd-a116-279894338e3f))
 INFO interface: info: Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
 INFO batch_action: Enabling parallelization by default.
 INFO batch_action: Disabling parallelization because provider doesn't support it: virtualbox
 INFO batch_action: Batch action will parallelize: false
 INFO batch_action: Starting action: #<Vagrant::Machine:0x00000100a0b3c8> up {:destroy_on_error=>true, :parallel=>true, :provision_ignore_sentinel=>false, :provision_types=>nil}
 INFO machine: Calling action: up on provider VirtualBox (0dd96364-f3ae-4bbd-a116-279894338e3f)
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x000001009ed2d8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::CheckVirtualbox:0x00000100ba4fe0>
 INFO base: VBoxManage path: VBoxManage
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "--version"]
DEBUG subprocess: Command not in installer, not touching env vars.
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: 4.2.18r88780
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 31999
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
DEBUG meta: Finding driver for VirtualBox version: 4.2.18
 INFO meta: Using VirtualBox driver: VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Driver::Version_4_2
 INFO base: VBoxManage path: VBoxManage
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "list", "hostonlyifs"]
DEBUG subprocess: Command not in installer, not touching env vars.
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Call:0x00000100ba4fb8>
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x00000100e53a20>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::Created:0x00000100e50910>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "showvminfo", "0dd96364-f3ae-4bbd-a116-279894338e3f", "--machinereadable"]
DEBUG subprocess: Command not in installer, not touching env vars.
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: name="vm_default_1382672231"

 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::Created:0x000001018e6f78>
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Warden:0x000001009edeb8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::CheckVirtualbox:0x00000100ba4ec8>
 INFO base: VBoxManage path: VBoxManage
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "--version"]
DEBUG subprocess: Command not in installer, not touching env vars.
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: 4.2.18r88780
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
DEBUG meta: Finding driver for VirtualBox version: 4.2.18
 INFO meta: Using VirtualBox driver: VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Driver::Version_4_2
 INFO base: VBoxManage path: VBoxManage
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "list", "hostonlyifs"]
DEBUG subprocess: Command not in installer, not touching env vars.
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x00000100ba4ea0>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Call:0x00000100ba4e78>
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x00000100cbe8b8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::IsRunning:0x00000100cbd1c0>
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "showvminfo", "0dd96364-f3ae-4bbd-a116-279894338e3f", "--machinereadable"]
DEBUG subprocess: Command not in installer, not touching env vars.
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stdout: name="vm_default_1382672231"
groups="/"
ostype="Linux 2.6"

DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::IsRunning:0x00000100cbd1c0>
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Warden:0x00000100d5ea48>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::MessageAlreadyRunning:0x00000100d5e9a8>
 INFO interface: info: VirtualBox VM is already running.
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::MessageAlreadyRunning:0x00000100d5e9a8>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Call:0x00000100ba4e78>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x00000100ba4ea0>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::CheckVirtualbox:0x00000100ba4ec8>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Call:0x00000100ba4f18>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x00000100ba4f40>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Call:0x00000100ba4fb8>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::CheckVirtualbox:0x00000100ba4fe0>
 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_unload
 INFO runner: Running action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x00000100e170c0>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have fixed itself by magic. After blowing away and cloning fresh from github the install works exactly as expected and all functionality works.